504 Error When Sending Requests to Flask RESTful Resources on PythonAnywhere
Hey I have a flask app and I am trying to host it on pythonanywhere. The app is running and I can visit the homepage at https://<my-username>.pythonanywhere.com. But when a user tries to log in the app is loading for a long time and then raise the following error in the error.log:
2024-04-14 02:58:03,007: Visited homepage.
2024-04-14 02:58:07,193: Visited homepage.
2024-04-14 02:58:14,103: User 'username' successfully logged in.
2024-04-14 03:03:14,522: POST request to https://<my-username>.pythonanywhere.com/api/users/2/update_last_seen failed with status code 504
2024-04-14 03:03:14,586: OSError: write error
2024-04-14 03:03:14,616: OSError: write error

When I tried this app on my local machine I didn't get this error. I don't have any idea why this is happening. Can anyone please help me to fix this?
Here is the structure of my app:
I am using a sqlite db. When the user. I have the following flask_restful resource written at /app/api/users.py:
class UpdateLastSeen(Resource):
    """
    - POST '/api/users/<int:user_id>/update_last_seen'
    """
    @token_required
    def post(self, user_id):
        # Retrieve the user from the database using user_id
        user = User.query.get_or_404(user_id)
        
        # Update the last_seen attribute of the user
        user.last_seen = utcnow()
        
        # Commit the changes to the database
        db.session.commit()
        
        return {'message': 'last_seen attribute updated successfully'}, 200

In my /app/auth/routes.py I have this following:
@auth_bp.before_request
def update_last_seen():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        user_id = current_user.id
        api_url = current_app.config['HOST'] + f'/api/users/{user_id}/update_last_seen'
        headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + current_app.config['SECRET_API_TOKEN']}
        
        try:
            response = requests.post(api_url, headers=headers)
            if response.status_code != 200:
                logger.error(f"POST request to {api_url} failed with status code {response.status_code}")
        except Exception as e:
            logger.exception(f"An error occurred while making a POST request to {api_url}: {e}")

In the last code block current_app.config['HOST'] is https://<my-username>.pythonanywhere.com which I have set in the Config class.
Problem. The problem that I understood is that in pythonanywhere.com the app cannot send any request to my flask_restful resources! Can anyone please help me how to get this work. Thanks!

I think' it's issue with permissions, your application try to write data to sqlite that is not corrected configured.
You can change the permissions of sqlite db or change to another folder so it can be writable by the applications
